Framing vaulted ceiling
Vaulted ceiling / framing question
Vaulted ceiling question.
Ok so we are in the process of renovating this room, which was an addition to our 1947 home. The room had a flat ceiling, and whoever made the extension, laid 2x6 rafters and laid them on the old asphalt roof, and landed them on top of the ceiling joists, and made half-assed sort of trusses. But the ceiling joists were cobbled together from various 2x4 parts. Structurally not a truss.
My original plan was to vault the ceiling. But as you can see, I can’t just cut out the ceiling joists. My thought was to sister in new 2x6’s and reverse bird mouth then, to land on the top palate. And the cut out the joists. Does this seem structurally feasible? On the top end of the joists , I plan on building a cripple wall to support the new/old rafters on top of a 2x12x10 (landed on jack studs, with kings…..could I get away with a 2x10x10 header? )
The roof is deck is a mix 3/4 tongue and groove, and plywood, with traditional felt, ice shield and rolled flat roof as its only a 2.5 pitch roof. The roof has no chimney and will never get solar, as the roof is north facing, and the south facing roof already has adequate solar. The room size is 8x11


Far more pics are needed to ascertain anything here.

Yeah I’m trying to add more

Pretty sure you need a structural engineer on site.

Probally, I’ll settle for a keyboard wizard though

It might help to sketch out what we're supposed to see in the pics—we can only see so much and it's all disconnected.
